# Making segmented roads appear as one line in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, road

I am footling around with QGIS and the British OS Strategi dataset. If I render the roads with a simple line style they look fine:

[image]

However, if I apply something slightly fancier, it looks wrong, because the style is applied to each segment of the road as opposed to the whole road (as we perceive it), as seen in the white lines on the blue motorway below:

[image]

How can I merge these segments together, or failing that force QGIS to treat them as one line?

I'm not using the data for navigation so I don't mind if the segments are lost.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Activate **symbol layers** in the advanced options of your road style.

With rule-dependent styles, check ***rendering order***. Terminology seems inconsistent unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You could duplicate the layer, then order them to the white line is drawn over the blue line.

Whilst you'd have to manage both layers, you do get better control over the appearance.

Answer (score 0):

To make your fancy style road, you can stack two lines with offsets, rather than a thin line on a large. You will have two beautiful lines without interruption even if you have multiple segments.

Answer (score 0):

To merge the road lines try selecting the vector line data that you want to merge.

Go to its 'properties' then select the 'style tab'.

Then in the 'symbols in group' section select 'advanced' a drop-down menu should appear select 'symbol levels'.

Then in the 'symbol levels' dialog box select 'Enable symbol levels', then click 'OK'.

Next select 'Apply' (to see if it has worked) and then 'OK' to confirm that you want this action to be carried out.

This should hopefully result in the road lines becoming merged.

You can also refer to this manual for more information:

https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=lines

Hope this helps! :)