# How do I make lines look "continues" (images inside)?

Tags: qgis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I merge segmented roads into one line?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40728/how-can-i-merge-segmented-roads-into-one-line)

A TAB file in MapInfo looks like this :

[image]

but when I import it to QGIS (and convert to shp) it looks like this :

[image]

How can I make the QGIS layer look like the MapInfo layer (I don't know the term of this functionality)

Comment: That answer doesn't help me.
I already used symbol layers and chose the "resindeal service road" style. but still the lines are overlapping.

Comment: Problem was solved by enabling "Symbol Levels".